# Help with this file upload script

Tags: php, file, upload

```
if (($ext=="zip")
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
     $newname = 'forms/'.$filename;
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$newname);
      mysqli_select_db($connect,"forms");
    $s = "update loc set loc='$newname' where sessionusername = '$u' AND name = '$name'";
   $q = mysqli_query($connect,$s);

    if($q)
    {
    header("Location:change.php");
    exit();
     }
    else
    {
    echo "Oops, something went haywire. Please try again";
    }

  }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file. Please try again.";
  }
  }
```

When i upload the file, i am getting error:1

UPDATE - CODE WORKS IN FF.NOT IN CHROME.

Comment: Is the page just outputting `1`? have you tried debugging or at the least putting `echo()` and finding out the path of the program? Might help

Comment: I Like "Oops, something went haywire. Please try again" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPLOAD_ERR_OK

```
Value: 0; There is no error, the file uploaded with success.
```

UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE

```
Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.
```

UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE

```
Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.
```

UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL

```
Value: 3; The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.
```

UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE

```
Value: 4; No file was uploaded.
```

UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR

```
Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.3.
```

UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE

```
Value: 7; Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.
```

UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION

```
Value: 8; A PHP extension stopped the file upload. PHP does not provide a way to ascertain which extension caused the file upload to stop; examining the list of loaded extensions with phpinfo() may help. Introduced in PHP 5.2.0.
```

Answer (score 1):

Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.